# Properly freeing memory space malloced in other function

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, valgrind, free

Edit : the problem isn't what I thought it was, check answers before reading my (long) question will spare you some time.

i've been valgrinding my little C project for school (basically a language detector), but there's a set of pointers I still have problems with according to valgrind. I think the problem is classic, it could be resumed in : How should I free a variable i malloced in another function when I (think I) have no choice ?

Here are the relevant parts of the two functions which cause me this problem. Basically, `get_modeles_names` gathers the filenames holding the right substring within them from my "collection" file; then `det_langue` is processing them.
Here is get_modeles_names :

```
    void get_modeles_names(int mode, char ** modeles)
{
        FILE * collection = get_collection_file();
        int i = 0;
        char * line = NULL;
        size_t size = 0;

        while (getline(&line, &size, collection) != -1) {
            if (strstr(line, entete)) {
                modeles[i] = (char*) malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof (char));
                modeles[i] = line;

                modeles[i][strlen(modeles[i]) - 1] = '\0';
                //replaces the final '\n' by '\0'

                i++;
                line = NULL;
            }
        }

        if (line)
            free(line);

        fclose(collection);
}
```

And here is det_langue :

```
void det_langue(char * w)
{
    int nb_modele = nb_modeles();

    char ** modeles = (char **) malloc(nb_modele * sizeof (char *));
    get_modeles_names(mode, modeles);

    double * resultats = (double *) malloc(nb_modele * sizeof (double));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nb_modele; i++) {
        resultats[i] = calculate_result (w, modeles[i]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nb_modele; i++) {
        free(modeles[i]);
    }
    free(modeles);
    free(resultats);
}
```

As you can see, i malloc my char ** modeles in det_langue to the right size (i am confident the nb_modeles function works fine) , then i malloc each element of modeles in get_modeles_names ; but since i need to process them later on, i can't free them (or don't know how) where i malloced them, i free them later, in the end of det_langue. I would think it's allright, but here's the output of `valgrind --leak-check=full ./projet -d pomme -m 1`

```
==30547== Command: ./projet -d pomme -m 1
==30547== 
pomme -> french
==30547== 
==30547== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30547==     in use at exit: 113 bytes in 4 blocks
==30547==   total heap usage: 40 allocs, 36 frees, 30,906 bytes allocated
==30547== 
==30547== 113 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==30547==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30547==    by 0x40163E: get_modeles_names (gestion_collection_modeles.c:120)
==30547==    by 0x401919: det_langue (det_langue.c:12)
==30547==    by 0x40189E: main (Main.c:76)
==30547== 
==30547== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30547==    definitely lost: 113 bytes in 4 blocks
==30547==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30547==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30547==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30547==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30547== 
==30547== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30547== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Line 120 is in get_modeles_names, it's : `modeles[i] = (char*) malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof (char));` Also, the size of modeles is 4, which explains for the 40 allocs but only 36 frees.
Also, if I go berserk and simply free modeles in the `get_modeles_names` function, my program obviously seg_faults, since the data i'm supposed to process don't exist anymore.

I've googled around, but couldn't find any question already asked which would answer mine .... any idea ?

Edit : the mem_leak was the one described in solution, but there is another as soon as it's solved : line leaks, which is solved by moving

```
if(line)
    free(line);
```

within the while loop.

Comment: I don't think someone will go throughout your code to find memory leaks, take this as an advice: `whoever allocates memory, has to clear it`. i.e. if you allocate a memory in `func foo` make sure to free it in `func foo` if it is no longer needed.

Comment: My question is : what should be my behaviour if the memory i allocate in func foo is still needed ?

Comment: Documentation and a clear interface. If you have `get_modeles_names` then you should provide a `free_modeles_names` function.

Comment: @m.raynal
If it is still needed, then don't free that memory.
Make sure the pointer is not lost otherwise you will have a memory leak.

Comment: BTW, never cast the return of `malloc()` and there is never a reason to multiply by `sizeof(char)` as it is _always_ `1` by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the following problem:

```
        if (strstr(line, entete)) {
            modeles[i] = (char*) malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof (char));
            modeles[i] = line;
```

Here, you first allocate memory with `malloc` and save the pointer to it in `modeles[i]` but then you overwrite the pointer with `line`. If you want to copy the contents of `line`, then use `strcpy`.

Note that you do not allocate enough memory for the `strcpy` of `line`: you forget the terminating null character. It should be:

```
            modeles[i] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
```

or:

```
            int len= strlen(line);
            line[len-2] = '\0';
            modeles[i] = malloc(len);
            strcpy(modeles[i], line);
```

.. and `sizeof(char)` is not needed because `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: Thanks, `All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible` .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
modeles[i] = line;
```

that is just replacing the pointer to the memory you malloc'd
You want a strcpy() there:

```
strcpy(models[i], line);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks really obvious once pointed at ! It revealed some other mem_leaks (now line is leaking, since I keep allocating then losing it in my loop), but from now on i can work on it.
And i'll remember the advice against casting my mallocs, so a double thanks !

Comment: Even if you right, this is a terrible answer:)). You never malloc a pointer or you malloc memory for a/the pointer (expression used often here), or whatever. There is only a malloc call made to the OS and if you get it you use your pointer to point to that requested memory location.

Comment: @john hascall : ok, I usually don't have the reputation to upvote, so I didn't bother trying :) And now I can see a pleasant `All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible` .....

Comment: @m.raynal Remember every time you assign a pointer to something or something to a pointer, this means that you pointer points to that (new) location and leaves the old one( if existed). That's way is called a Pointer.